# WPF, RichTextBox, SelectionBrush, not SelectionBackColor

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

In a WPF app RichTextBox, I'm trying to find a way to provide a background color for various words within the box.  In the System.Windows.Forms version of the RichTextBox, there was a very simple way to do this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = color;
richTextBox1.AppendText(word);
```

However, the System.Windows.Controls version of RichTextBox only has SelectionBrush, and this same method does not work.

Is a background color for different words in the RichTextBox possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with the `FlowDocument` within the `RichTextBox`

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Background="Red">Hello World</Run>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Background="Green">This is a colored</Run>
                <Run>text.</Run>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox.Document>
</RichTextBox>
```

**Edit regarding your comments:** a (nearly) full example showing two different approaches.

No matter what you end up doing to present your text in the UI, you should have some sort of logic that creates a suitable data model of your highlighted text. The following example uses a collection of `TextFragment` where each fragment is optionally marked as highlighted.

```
public class TextFragment
{
    public TextFragment(string text, bool isHighlighted)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.IsHighlighted = isHighlighted;
    }
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public bool IsHighlighted { get; private set; }
}
```

Also, for the sample I use a class `TextEntry` to manage original text, search text and the resulting text fragments. Note I inherit from a `BaseViewModel` class which implements some helper functions for `INotifyPropertyChanged` related things. The helper function `bool SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)` will check whether value and store are equal, potentially update the store with value and raise a property changed notification. The return value indicates, whether the value was really different/changed.

```
public class TextEntry : BaseViewModel
{
    public TextEntry()
    {
        TextParts = new ObservableCollection<TextFragment>();
    }

    private void UpdateTextParts()
    {
        TextParts.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
        {
            TextParts.Add(new TextFragment(OriginalText, false));
            return;
        }

        int startAt = 0;
        do
        {
            int next = OriginalText.IndexOf(SearchText, startAt, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (next == -1)
            {
                TextParts.Add(new TextFragment(OriginalText.Substring(startAt), false));
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (next != startAt)
                {
                    TextParts.Add(new TextFragment(OriginalText.Substring(startAt, next - startAt), false));
                }
                // add highlighted part
                TextParts.Add(new TextFragment(OriginalText.Substring(next, SearchText.Length), true));
                startAt = next + SearchText.Length;
            }
        } while (startAt < OriginalText.Length);
    }


    private string _OriginalText;
    public string OriginalText
    {
        get { return _OriginalText; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _OriginalText, value))
            {
                UpdateTextParts();
            }
        }
    }


    private string _SearchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _SearchText; }
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _SearchText, value))
            {
                UpdateTextParts();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TextFragment> TextParts { get; private set; }
}
```

You can create a multi-part text in the UI by appending multiple textblocks with different text settings in a horizontal `StackPanel`. This way, the text parts can be managed by an `ItemsControl`. Alternatively, you can use the `RichTextBox` with its `Document` property, but this needs some more handling in code behind.

Some initialization code in the main window and a method to update the document for the `RichTextBox` example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new TextEntry();
    grid1.DataContext = vm;
    // this trigger works, but don't ask about efficiency for a bigger application
    vm.TextParts.CollectionChanged += TextParts_CollectionChanged;
}

void TextParts_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<TextFragment> data = sender as ObservableCollection<TextFragment>;
    var doc = richTextBox1.Document;
    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.Inlines.AddRange(data.Select(x =>
    {
        var run = new Run(x.Text);
        if (x.IsHighlighted)
        {
            run.Background = Brushes.LightCoral;
        }
        return run;
    }));
    doc.Blocks.Clear();
    doc.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
}
```

And the XAML content of the window:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Original Text: " Margin="3"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Searched Word: " Margin="3"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Highlighted Text: " Margin="3"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Highlighted Text2: " Margin="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OriginalText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SearchText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TextParts}" Margin="3" IsTabStop="False">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <RichTextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="richTextBox1" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>
```

Expected Program:

Two lines with text inputs. One for the original text, one for the searched text.

3rd line showing the original text with search highlights as `TextBlock`s.

4th line showing the original text with search highlights as `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Thank you for the response grek40, that is helpful.  I'll need to do this programatically as my text is not static and bound, via a DependencyProperty.  Ultimately what I need is to get the text of the bound property, highlight certain words in that text, and display that result in the RichTextBox.  So it seems as though I'll have to build something like the FlowDocument above in code?

Comment: @Mike. I think thats the way to go... however there might be other approaches. If your text originates from code and is not input by user, do you even need a `RichTextBox` (does the user manipulate the text later)? Because multi-colored text can be presented in different ways if its just about showing it without user interaction.

Comment: No user manipulation of this text.  Here is what happens (or what I need to happen):  1) Grid is loaded with rows of text  2) User enters "filter" text in a different textbox above the grid  3) Any entries in the grid containing filter text entered by user are highlighted.  So if the grid contains two rows of data, row 1 = "Sport of football" row 2 = "Football is my favorite sport" and user enters sport in the search textbox, sport should be highlighted in each of the rows above.  I though RichTextBox in the grid template column would be the only way to do the highlighting of individual words.

Comment: (cont'd) But, if there are other ways to do what I need via some other control, I'd value other suggestions.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike. You see, when you have so much text that you need to continue your comment, it is about time you edit your question and just comment a quick notice like "added details to the question" ;)

Comment: That solution is greatly appreciated and it works very well.  I will adapt it to my particular situation with a fair amount of data and see how it goes...well I expect since my data set will be fairly limited already.  Can't tell you how much I appreciate you taking the time to come up with that.